# .htaccess redirct causes loop

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to make some redirect like this:

```
Redirect 301 /foo /foo/bar/index.html
```

Problem is, it creates a loop.

Intuitively I would expect this redirect would match `/foo` only and not `/foo.*`. But apparently things work differently. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect` to be able to use regex for exact matching:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/foo/?$ /foo/bar/index.html
```

Make sure to use a new browser for testing this change.

Regex `^/foo/?$` will only match `/foo` or `/foo/` but not `/foo/anything`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example `.htaccess` file of mine.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
Redirect 301 /CPP001/ https://mydomainaddress.com/cpp/student-app/
Redirect 301 /DSE001/ https://mydomainaddress.com/cpp/examples/virtual.html
Redirect 301 /DSE002/ https://mydomainaddress.com/cpp/examples/overload.html
Redirect 301 /ANK001/ https://mydomainaddress.com/cpp/com267/
Redirect 301 /ANK002/ https://mydomainaddress.com/c-programming/com267HW2/
Redirect 301 /WEB001/ https://mydomainaddress.com/web-programming/examples/index.html
Redirect 301 /NET001/ https://mydomainaddress.com/pdf/IPControl.pdf
ErrorDocument 404 https://mydomainaddress.com/
ErrorDocument 403 https://mydomainaddress.com/
```

Try to change your `Redirect 301 /foo /foo/bar/index.html` to `Redirect 301 /foo http://yourdomain.com/foo/bar/index.html`

If nothing inside `index.html` is causing another redirection, it's highly unlikely a loop will happen again.